# Making Google Logo grey scale on Google Translate Button

Tags: html, embed, google-translate

I would like to make the Google Logo that appears in the Google Translate Button into grey scale (i.e. not bright green, red, blue, yellow).  Is there any simple code (I am not a coder) I can add to this embed code to make this happen?  This is the embed code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {  

  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout:   
  google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE},   
 'google_translate_element');
  }
  </script><script type="text/javascript"  
  src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?  
  cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply add some css code after your current javascript code-block:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<style media="screen">
  #google_translate_element img.goog-te-gadget-icon {
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @MathewAldred please accept the answer if it works for you and you are satisfied with my answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for detailed informations about "accepting an answer".

Comment: Thank you @benedikt - just what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. :-)